# Painting a movie in Android

Tags: java, android, video

I'm trying to make an Stop-motion movie creator over Android. I'd like to decode a movie file (mpg, avi, mp4...) and play only some frames (not all). Painting it periodically over a Canvas.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Please see my modified answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to decode a movie file (mpg, avi, mp4...) and play only some frames (not all).

Android does not really support this offcially. You may end up using the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html), using third-party video codec [library, like ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to decode a frame.

**EDIT** : It turns out that Android supports this after-all

[getFrameAtTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28long,%20int%29)

> Call this method after setDataSource(). This method finds a representative frame close to the given time position by considering the given option if possible, and returns it as a bitmap. This is useful for generating a thumbnail for an input data source or just obtain and display a frame at the given time position.